# AngularJS: How to set Filter by click

Tags: angularjs

How do I set specific search conditions like: `search.date > someDate()` or `search.amount > 0`

I've tried: `<a href="#" ng-click="search.amount = x > 0">Pos only</a>` etc.etc.

I currently have an input with:
`<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search all" ng-model="search" />`
That works great and searches all fields. It breaks when I try a specific filter putting `[object Object]` in the search input.

```
<tr ng-repeat="tenant in tenants | filter:search | orderBy:sort" >
  <td>{{tenant.rent | currency: "€&nbsp;"}}</td>
  <td>{{tenant.name}}</td>
  <td>{{tenant.tel}}</td>
  <td><a href="mailto:{{tenant.mail}}">{{tenant.mail}}</a></td>
  <td>{{tenant.amount }}</td>
  <td>{{tenant.date}}</td>
</tr>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/pjsx1460/12/)**

How do I set these kind of filters (without breaking the global search)?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do...  You use the condition "search.amount > 0" but there is no attribute called "amount" in your tenant objects. On the other hand, there is a object "search" which contains date and amount, but there is also another variable called "search" as a model in your text input, are they the same object?

Comment: Updated the template! Everywhere `search` is mentioned it means the same thing. I'm using it for `filter:search`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `ng-hide` statement for virtual filtering `ng-hide="search.minAmount > tenant.account"`. Since you used search as an object, I initialised it as one in the controller:

```
$scope.search = {};
$scope.search.text = "";
$scope.search.minAmount = null;
```

And set the filter as along with an `ng-hide`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="tenant in tenants | filter:search.text | orderBy:sort:reverse" ng-class="{danger: payment.diff > 0}" ng-hide="search.minAmount != null && search.minAmount > tenant.account">
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pjsx1460/15/)

**PS**: You can change what you want positive, `account` or `rent`.

Comment: I love your solution, too bad it messes with the "even/odd" styling of the table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to pass a object to filter, this object must contain the same attributes of your list objects, for example, to find out `tenants` whose `name` contains "a", you can pass a object `{name:"a"}` to filter

```
tenant in tenants | filter:{name:"a"} | orderBy:sort
```

So you may misunderstand the filter usage...

---

To achieve what you want, you can customize your own filter with the `$filter` service. Here is an example:

In controller:

```
angular.module('ngAppRentManager', []).
controller('RentCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.search = {
        keyword: "",
        pos_only: false
    }

    $scope.getFilteredTenants = function() {
        var filtered_tenants = $scope.tenants;
        filtered_tenants = $filter("filter")(filtered_tenants, $scope.search.keyword);
        if ($scope.search.pos_only) {
            filtered_tenants = $filter("filter")(filtered_tenants, function(tenant) {
                return tenant.amount > 0;
            });
        }
        filtered_tenants = $filter("orderBy")(filtered_tenants, $scope.sort, $scope.reverse);
        return filtered_tenants;
    };

}]);
```

In html:

```
<li><a href="#" ng-click="search.pos_only = true">Pos only</a></li>
<li><a href="#" ng-click="search.pos_only = false">All</a></li>

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search all" ng-model="search.keyword" />

<tr ng-repeat="tenant in getFilteredTenants()" ng-class="{danger: payment.diff > 0}">
    <td>{{tenant.rent | currency: "€&nbsp;"}}</td>
    <td>{{tenant.name}}</td>
    <td>{{tenant.tel}}</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:{{tenant.mail}}">{{tenant.mail}}</a></td>
    <td>{{tenant.amount}}>
    <td>{{tenant.address}}</td>
</tr>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hree359z/2/)